# SSIS event handler

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Please I need some help,
I'm trying to get information about SSIS error
i use event handler. i try to catch the error using system variable error description
then I insert the error on a table, but this system variable holds the task error and I want to insert the error line not the task execution error on the table because it is more readable

when i go to execution results i have two lines of error :

one with error :XXX

and other with [execution task ] error : XXX

[image]

infos :

- i can't use the handler on the top tree of the package cause i have other errors to manage.
- i'm using the same mechanism on other containers on the same package
- i catch the error from the Control flow not the data flow

i'm using event handler and on the event i have a task update table set comment =? where id = ?

[image]

thanks you so much

Comment: The error is saying you're inserting a duplicate key, by the looks of it.

Comment: thx i know this is the error i want to insert this error on the table log not the error below, the system variable holds the second line not the first one.

Comment: Can you clarify which error messages are being written to your database, it sounds like you are capturing both of them already? Is it that you want to capture the first one only?

Comment: i want to capture the first one, or both but with this method  i'm capturing the second one only

Comment: Could you share the SQL statement for your error handler? I would also try debugging this with a `Script Task` error handler that just displays `MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["System::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString());` to see if that will pick up the error.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's your SQL statement that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your event handler SQL that is causing the problem:

```
update table set comment = ? where id = ?
```

You are overwriting the first error message with the second one.

To capture them both, use an `INSERT` instead.

**Edit**

If you only want to insert the first error message, you could add a `Boolean` variable to your SSIS package, called 'ErrorSet', for example, which is set to `false` at the start of the package. You could then pass this in to the error handler and do something like (where the first `?` is 'ErrorSet'):

```
IF ? = 0
    update table set comment = ? where id = ?
;

SELECT CAST(1 AS bit) ErrorSet
```

You would then write the 'ErrorSet' result back out into the SSIS package variable, which would prevent any further updates from occurring.

You could also scope this to different areas of your package, either by using different variables, or by resetting the same variable back to `false`.

Comment: maybe you're right but i have already the column with an id i just want to update the column with error message can i say update only once  or other thing ?

Comment: thx i have add the script task and i have the first message then the second message
so i update with the last error, is there any solution so i can insert both of them or only the first one

Comment: I added an expression task to force the value to put it directly in the table

Comment: I updated my answer with an idea that may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

from @ChrisMack answer:

> It's your event handler SQL that is causing the problem:
>
> ```
> update table set comment = ? where id = ?
> ```
>
> You are overwriting the first error message with the second one.

I added an expression task to force the value to put it directly in the table.